# Why is unexpected keyword argument 'typ' error thrown?

Tags: python, statsmodels

For typical integer values of `p`, `d`, `q` and a list of numbers, `rollRate`, the following code:

```
fit = statsmodels.api.tsa.ARIMA(rollRate, (p,d,q)).fit()
forecast = fit.predict(start=len(rollRate),
                       end = len(rollRate)+11,
                       typ = 'levels')
```

produces an error that I don't understand:

> File "C:...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\wrapper.py", line 92, in wrapper
>       return data.wrap_output(func(results, *args, **kwargs), how)
>
> TypeError: predict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'typ'

I have also successfully predicted with other list variables, but this particular list is giving me an error.  Any idea as to why `predict()` isn't accepting `typ` as a keyword argument when [the source code says that it can](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/tsa/arima_model.py#L1756)?

Comment: Check the type of intermediate objects (`print(type(fit)` for example, or `print` without parentheses for Python 2).

Comment: Also, you could provide the values of the input parameters, so other people could reproduce the issue.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the version described in that source code?

Comment: `print(type(fit))
<class 'statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMAResultsWrapper'>`

p=1, d=0, q=0.   I'm running python 3.4 in Spyder using statsmodels latest version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I see the issue. You don't have an ARIMA model. You have an ARMA model because `d=0`. `ARMA.predict` doesn't take a `typ` keyword argument because they don't need one.

Comment: I see...sorry, that was dumb of me Lol

Comment: It's not dumb, really...if the docs say that an argument is expected, it should be handled. It's not clear from the docs that ARIMA.predict() uses an ARMA underneath that doesn't accept the argument.